# Jenkins Slack Integration Test Connection Fails

Tags: jenkins

Can anyone provide any insight into how to debug why the Test Connection button in Jenkins fails.

We do have a webcontent filtering system and I'm assuming that because Jenkins runs as a local system account that it's not being permitted by that filter.

Aside from changing the filter to ALLOW all to Slack is there any other way to confirm it's a filter issue? Can I issue a test from a command line to see it's output etc...